# Xuggler can't open IContainer of icecast server [Webm live video stream]

Tags: ffmpeg, xuggler

I'm trying to stream a live webm  stream.

I tested some server and Icecast is my pic.

With ffmpeg capturing from an IP camera and publishing in icecast server I'm able to see video in html5

using this command:

ffmpeg.exe -rtsp_transport tcp -i "rtsp://192.168.230.121/profile?token=media_profile1&SessionTimeout=60" -f webm -r 20 -c:v libvpx -b:v 3M -s 300x200 -acodec none -content_type video/webm -crf 63 -g 0 icecast://source:hackme@192.168.0.146:8001/test

I'm using java and tryed to make this with xuggler, but I'm getting an error when opening the stream

```
 final String urlOut = "icecast://source:hackme@192.168.0.146:8001/agora.webm";
    final IContainer    outContainer = IContainer.make();

    final IContainerFormat outContainerFormat = IContainerFormat.make();
    outContainerFormat.setOutputFormat("webm", urlOut, "video/webm");

    int rc = outContainer.open(urlOut, IContainer.Type.WRITE, outContainerFormat);

    if(rc>=0) {
    }else  {
        Logger.getLogger(WebmPublisher.class.getName()).log(Level.INFO, "Fail to open Container " + IError.make(rc));
    }
```

Any help?
I'm getting the error -2:
 Error: could not open file (../../../../../../../csrc/com/xuggle/xuggler/Container.cpp:544)

It's is also very importatn to set the content type as video/webm because icecast by default set the mime type to audio/mpeg